# Appending directory with Apache URL Rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a client that needs to access one web server directly but they have a peculiar setup.

There is a sub folder in their `DocumentRoot` called `public_html` and there sits the contents that should be public facing. Their load balancer serves contents in their directory to their domain http://domain.com/

I'm trying to write a URL rewrite to append `public_html` if they access via the server IP, so the referenced css and images are loaded correctly.

Here what I got on the .htaccess file on the `public_html` folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1.2.3.4
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/public_html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public_html/$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Any idea why it is not working?

Comment: This IP `1.2.3.4` is true?

Answer (score 0):

RewriteCond takes a regex as the second argument so I doubt the rule is correct for your `REQUEST_URI`. The following may work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1.2.3.4$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public_html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public_html/$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```